# Assign incremental values to dynamically generated checkboxes in knockout

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I want to assign unique incremental values to dynamically generated checkboxes, starting from 0 onwards and incrementing by 1, (i.e, the checkboxes values should be 0,1,2,3 and so on). I have the following code snippet which is kind of an abstract of the bigger picture :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>
    <script src="knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:arr">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : $root.ch, attr : {value : $root.ci}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click:add">Click</button>
<button data-bind="click:func">Checked</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        ci : ko.observable("0"),
        ch : ko.observableArray([]) ,
        arr : ko.observableArray([]),
        add : function(){
            alert(viewModel.ci());
            viewModel.arr.push("something");
            var temp = Number(viewModel.ci());
            temp++;
            viewModel.ci(ko.toJSON(temp));
        },
        func : function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < viewModel.ch().length; i++)
            {
                alert(viewModel.ch()[i]);
            }
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Initially, the UI will contain a 'Click' button and a 'Checked' button. Once the user clicks on 'Click', a new checbox is generated and value is assigned to it based on the above logic. When the user clicks 'Checked', the values of all the checkboxes are alerted one by one. Now, here's the catch : on clicking checked, it displays the values of the selected checkboxes just fine, but when you select 'Inspect element' from the browser on the checboxes, all the checkboxes get the same value which is equal to the number of checkboxes created. How to resolve this issue so that the checkboxes will have incremental values?

Comment: Why are you jumping through hoops to store `ci` as a  *string*?

Comment: And why use `ko.toJSON` to convert a simple number to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are all the same because that's what you're telling KO to do, here:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : $root.ch, attr : {value : $root.ci}">
<!-- -------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   -->
```

If you want the values to be different, you need to have something there that isn't the same for all checkboxes.

If you really want `0`, `1`, `2`, and so on, conveniently you already have something `foreach` gives you: `$index`. Also note that you can use the `value` binding rather than `attr: { value: ... }`

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : $root.ch, value : $index}">
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var viewModel = {
  ci: ko.observable("0"),
  ch: ko.observableArray([]),
  arr: ko.observableArray([]),
  add: function() {
    alert(viewModel.ci());
    viewModel.arr.push("something");
    var temp = Number(viewModel.ci());
    temp++;
    viewModel.ci(ko.toJSON(temp));
  },
  func: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.ch().length; i++) {
      alert(viewModel.ch()[i]);
    }
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:arr">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : $root.ch, value: $index">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click:add">Click</button>
<button data-bind="click:func">Checked</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```